# CLR Function publish.sql file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools, sqlclr

I have a CLR function that I want to deploy with `permission_set = unsafe`

The assembly is signed with a public/private key file and I've created an `assymtric key`, created a `login` using that `asymmetric key` and given that login the permission for `unsafe` assemblies

If I want to deploy the assembly can I just execute the .publish.sql found under ./bin/debug be used to deploy the CLR assembly .dll?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes you can if the publish config is properly configured (I mean that there is no ignoring of CLRs or smf like that)

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Is it as simple as opening the file in SSMS and click execute? I don't need to tell it where the public/private key.

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, you **shouldn't** be deploying unsafe assemblies. You probably don't need them, eg you *shouldn't* try to send emails from SQLCLR. Or use it to load CSV files. Or execute queries. Or anything else that should be performed by SQL Server agent, SSIS, external tools. Any wasted RAM or CPU cycles are taken from the server's memory and CPU resources, thus *harming* performance

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze what does this assembly do? Why a SQLCLR assembly and why unsafe?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Converts GridRefs to LatLongs and vice versa using .NET methods, `Unsafe` because i get the error **Storing to a static field is not allowed in safe assemblies**.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze then *don't* store in a static field. You don't need it. If you want to gather data, create an aggregate.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze There's good reason why you get that error message: it is highly error prone given the shared App Domain that ALL sessions access. Static values are shared, so it's real easy to have sessions step over each other's value. This can lead to odd / bad behavior. Static fields only make sense when caching values that are valid for ALL sessions at any given moment. And if it is a simple cache, then make it a collection that is marked `readonly` and set the Assembly to `SAFE`. You can add/remove from readonly collections in `SAFE`. I have an example on here I will try to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already set up the perquisite stuff, then I am curious as to why you didn't just attempt to execute that file to see for yourself as that would have answered this question, right? ;-) But yes, those three steps are all you need to do in order to be create (and use) an Assembly marked with `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`.

Keep in mind that the "publish" script is always incremental. So you shouldn't take it as being a deployment script that will work in all situations. If you have done a build and made no changes, then it won't re-deploy the Assembly, unless there is an option to always drop-recreate the objects (I know there is for the database but don't remember for the Assembly). The "create" script, if you checked the option to generate it, always drops everything and recreates.

And just in case this was implied, the publish scripts generated by SSDT do not, by default, mess with server-level objects that are not part of the project ("part of the project" means that you have imported the `master` DB into the solution). So the full Create script won't (or at least shouldn't) remove the Login or Asymmetric Key from `[master]`. But, if needed, there are options for "Do not drop Logins" and/or "Do not drop Asymmetric Keys".

AND, just to mention since this question regards an older version of SQL Server: SQL Server 2017, which was just released, changes the rules a little for deploying Assemblies. The method described in the question will still work as it creates the Asymmetric Key first, but that is now required even for `SAFE` Assemblies. I describe (in detail) two options for dealing with this that both a) work in all versions back to SQL Server 2012, and b) work with the framework of Visual Studio and SSDT in a fully automated manner:

- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

That first link (for Solution 1), is an adaptation of the method detailed in the following article that I wrote for SQL Server Central and that does work with SQL Server 2005 - SQL Server 2016:

[Stairway to SQLCLR Level 7: Development and Security](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/138155/)

Comment: "the publish scripts generated by SSDT do not mess with server-level objects" that's not true. You can easily add logins to the projects and so on. There is an option to enable/disable it and most commonly it is desabled

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev True, I was just speaking generically in terms of SQLCLR projects because that usually never comes up since this is handled outside of SSDT. But, I just updated my answer to clarify. Hopefully the new wording is more accurate. Thanks for pointing that out.